# How can I click the tab bar to pop up a modal xcode

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I want to click tab bar to pop up a modal view not just view controller.

(Like Instagram's camera tab bar to pup up camera view)

However when I drag from navigation controller to another view controller

[image: i drag from navigation controller to view controller]

I always got a black view when I run the app if I choose present modally.

So now, I can only choose root view controller.

Sorry for my poor English !

Can anyone understand and help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to subclass uitabbarcontroller and use its delegate:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
  if  ([viewController isKindOfClass:[SomeVC class]])  {
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:vcToPresentModal animated:YES completion:NULL];
    return NO;
  }
  return YES;
}
```

The main idea is to catch selection of some vc(it could be just empty UIViewController, connected with item, where should be modal presentation), cancel it,and show a modal vc.

Comment: Thank you. It did help me a lot.